# How to select parent div of a form in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is what i got

```
<div id="right">
    <from id="test">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </div>
```

and a lil jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){


        $('form').submit(function()
                         {
                             $(this).parent().html('<h1>1</h1>');
                         });
    });
```

you can play with [that here](http://jsfiddle.net/W9S4F/),

and by clicking on submit button it should put `<h1>1</h1>` in `div#right` but it don't !

Cause `this` is a form in this case but it works with button label or any thing else and I think that is because form is not a DOM node.

So how can I select the parent of a form, or in other words how can i select the `Div` that contents the `form` ?

Update: as it was a part of an ajax call i wanted to break it down and find the problem 
but i had made a typo which cost me an hour or so, but the problem with ajax was that you `$(this)` inside `success:` is not the form any more so i did like this

```
    `$('form').submit(function(){
        form = $(this);//  I set the form to a varible !!

                 $.ajax({



   type: "POST", url: "ajax.php", data: $(this).serialize(),

                success: function(data){
                    $(form).parent().html(data); // I used the varible i set to form before!
                               }});`
```

anyways, how can i mark this question as solved ?!

Comment: It'd probably help if your form was tagged `form`, not `from`...

Comment: @Chowett: Damn it i am Struggling with a typo for an hour and so!, thanks for answer anyways.

Comment: Post your solution as new Answer and accept it. (Think you have to wait 15 minutes before you can accept)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it was a part of an ajax call i wanted to break it down and find the problem but i had made a typo which cost me an hour or so, but the problem with ajax was that $(this) inside success: is not the form any more so i did like this

```
$('form').submit(function(){
        form = $(this);//  I set the form to a varible !!

                 $.ajax({



   type: "POST", url: "ajax.php", data: $(this).serialize(),

                success: function(data){
                    $(form).parent().html(data); // I used the varible i set to form before!
                               }});
```

Answer (score 3):

As Chowlett says, use form rather than from.

That code will then work, because the $(this) inside the submit function will select the form element, the parent of which is is the #right div.

You could use .parent('div') to make sure you select a div, and not anything else.